# Import JSON document array / object to a Meteor Collection with correct _ids

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor

What is the best way to import a 15,000 document json file of a format (but with a +30 foo fields)

```
[{"foo1":"foo1data1", "foo2":"foo2data1"}, {"foo1":"foo1data2", "foo2":"foo2data2"}...           
{"foo1":"foo1dataN", "foo2":"foo2dataN"}])
```

to a Meteor collection?
I tried with mongoimport but that created ObjectID's instead of _id's and I could not make it work without autopublish, although other collections, created with Meteor, work just fine on client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing the file is located on the server under `pathToFile` you can do something like this:

```
var fs = Npm.require("fs");
var Fiber = Npm.require("fibers");

fs.readFile(pathToFile, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  // handle error if there is some

  data = JSON.parse(data);

  Fiber(function () {

    _.each(data, function (document) {
      SomeMeteorCollection.insert(document);
    });

  }).run();
});
```

Please note that `Fiber` wrapper is required if you want call any **meteor** specific routines, for example **collections API**, within some **nodejs** asynchronous code.

Comment: Thx!!! Sorry to pose a question with no "tried this" code, but I am new to node/mongo/meteor and the reason I've chosen meteor is because my project depends on live real-world API json data and I got the impression that I would be able to just import the file to mongodb directly, which I tried but went into problems with ObjectID instead if _id... Anyway, now it works like a charm! Thx